# Draw rectangle with line in centre using Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image: Sample]Please help me how can I draw rectangle joining center line as shown in figure
Below is my code for drawing rectangle on mouse down on canvas, What I am trying to do is to draw a line in center of rectangle which will make it as one shape of my canvas

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (option) {
            console.log(option);
            if (typeof option.target != "undefined") {
                return;
            } else {
                var startY = option.e.offsetY,
                    startX = option.e.offsetX;

                console.log(startX, startY);

                var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
                    top : startY,
                    left : startX,
                    width : 0,
                    height : 0,
                    fill : 'transparent',
                    stroke: 'red',
                    strokewidth: 4
                });

                canvas.add(rect2);
                console.log("added");
                canvas.on('mouse:move', function (option) {
                    var e = option.e;
                    rect2.set('width', e.offsetX - startX);
                    rect2.set('height', e.offsetY - startY);
                    rect2.setCoords();
                });


            }
        });

        canvas.on('mouse:up', function () {
            canvas.off('mouse:move');
        });
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid red;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have added line at centre of rectangle now I want to add Line and rectangle to groups.